# data size difference when copying with bufferedstream in java

Tags: java, io

When I copy file with bufferedstream in java, copied file looks size difference compare with original. Why does it happens? (However, file was perfectly works)

This is my code:

```
fileIn = new FileInputStream("guitar_sim.mp3");
bufferIn = new BufferedInputStream(fileIn);
fileOut = new FileOutputStream("test_song1.mp3");
bufferOut = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOut);

//int data = 0;
byte[] data = new byte[1000]; 
long startT = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
while((bufferIn.read(data))!=-1) {
    bufferOut.write(data);
}
long endT = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
System.out.println(endT-startT);
```

Output:

```
Mon Jul 27 15:56:52 KST 2015
Mon Jul 27 15:56:53 KST 2015
102
```

Original data size : 2871KB (guitar_sim.mp3)
Copied data size : 2868KB (test_song1.mp3)

Comment: You forgot to flush and close the outputStream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way a better approach is to use [try-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). It invokes the final flush and close automatically.

Now to your problem. The read method returns the number of bytes which has been read to the buffer. In fact you're writing too much bytes to your `OutputStream`. Here is a possible solution:

```
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("guitar_sim.mp3");
     OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("test_song1.mp3")) {
  byte[] data = new byte[2048];
  int size;
  while ((size = is.read(data)) != -1) {
    os.write(data, 0, size);
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can also use the NIO to copy files via [Files#copy(Path, Path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-).

Comment: It invokes the final `close()` automatically. `close()` calls `flush()` in output streams that extend `FilterOutputStream`, i.e. may have `flush()` implementations either of their own or of the wrapped output stream, but `FileOutputStream` isn't one of them.